# How to write backslash in Apple script

Tags: applescript, pdf

I want to do this from the shell with an Apple Script:

```
/System/Library/Automator/Combine\ PDF\ Pages.action/Contents/MacOS/join -o output inpath1 inpath2
```

However I don't know how to write backslash without it raising an error.

This is just with empty spaces:

```
set inpath1 to "/Users/user1/Dropbox/z_Scripts/ex1.pdf"
set inpath2 to "/Users/user1/Dropbox/z_Scripts/ex2.pdf"

do shell script "/System/Library/Automator/Combine\\ PDF\\ Pages.action/Contents/MacOS/join -o output " & inpath1 & "\\ " & inpath2
```

How to add the backslash? Any thoughts?

Comment: This is because adding a backslash in the middle of a string there cuts the string at where the backslash is.

Comment: What is the error given?

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) What is it you're trying to do? Presumably your action is called 'Combine PDF Pages.action' not 'Combine\ PDF\ Pages.action' so your escapes are already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is the AppleScript way:

```
set inpath1 to quoted form of "/Users/user1/Dropbox/z_Scripts/ex1.pdf"
set inpath2 to quoted form of "/Users/user1/Dropbox/z_Scripts/ex2.pdf"
do shell script quoted form of "/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/MacOS/join" & " -o output " & inpath1 & " " & inpath2
```

The command being executed by bash for the script above is:

```
'/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/MacOS/join' -o output '/Users/user1/Dropbox/z_Scripts/ex1.pdf' '/Users/user1/Dropbox/z_Scripts/ex2.pdf'
```

However, the way I read your question leads me to think you want this:

```
on quotedform from s
    do shell script "printf '%q' " & quoted form of s
end quotedform

set inpath1 to quotedform from "/Users/user1/Dropbox/z_Scripts/ex1.pdf"
set inpath2 to quotedform from "/Users/user1/Dropbox/z_Scripts/ex2.pdf"
set z to (quotedform from "/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/MacOS/join") & " -o output " & inpath1 & " " & inpath2
```

The command being executed by bash for the script above is:

```
/System/Library/Automator/Combine\ PDF\ Pages.action/Contents/MacOS/join -o output /Users/user1/Dropbox/z_Scripts/ex1.pdf /Users/user1/Dropbox/z_Scripts/ex2.pdf
```

I believe using `quoted form of` alone would be safer. I imagine there are situations where `quotedform from` would fail.